# Outlook sends appointment to wrong mail address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Following scenario:

- User has some "John Doe" as contact in their Outlook with two email addresses *Email* = `john.doe@business.example`  and *Email2* = `john.doe@private.example`
- User wants to invite John Doe to a business meeting and therefore types their business mail address `john.doe@business.example` into the participant field. It is shown as `john.doe@business.example` (and not as John Doe, say).
- User submits the meeting. Opening it again in the calendar still shows the business mail `john.doe@business.example`, as desired
- But checking in the *Sent Mails* folder, however, it turns out that it was actually sent to `john.doe@private.example` (with the consequence that John Doe did not receive the mail during work hours and missed the meeting)

Why?? How??

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this has been solved but I found an ANSWER after having the same problem. It seems to be related to the "Microsoft 365 shared calendar improvements".

If you go to **File > Account Settings > Data Files**...
and then only on your Microsoft Exchange account:
...**Settings > Advanced > Switch off the "Microsoft 365 features"** i.e. disable the "Turn on shared calendar improvements"

This should solve the problem of your Microsoft Exchange email accounts taking priority over IMAP or other account.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur in Outlook client? If so, in order to check whether this issue is related to the contact account, please conduct the same test on web mail to check if it can be sent correctly.

And did you use autocomplete to fill in the recipient address? If so, please try to type the recipient email address manually to see if there're any differences.

In addition, I noticed that you tried to send a meeting to this contact. Does this issue also occur when someone else sends a meeting to the contact account? And except sending meetings, can you send ordinary mail to the contact's address successfully?

For better research, please provide the above relevant information.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.